# Remove close button for Firefox SDK-toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to know how to style a Firefox addon toolbar using the SDK. For example, a toolbar will have a 3d-border around it with a close button on the right. How can I remove/modify this?

here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnLfZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

( I'm assuming you are using this apis: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_toolbar )

The short answer is, you can't, and this is by design. The user should always be able to easily remove your toolbar.

Comment: I think "you cant remove the close button" is a really bad choice by Firefox Developers, because for example in my case i'm building a toolbar for internal use (my company) and this should never be cosed. The ability to disable/remove the close button should be a must.